# Show that a sequence is a Cauchy sequence

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

Suppose that $(x_n)$ is a decreasing sequence of non-negative real numbers that converges to 0.  Prove, using the definition, that the sequence $(y_n)$ where $y_n = x_1 - x_2 + x_3 - x_4 + \cdots + (-1)^{n{+1}}x_n$ is a Cauchy sequence.

I understand that a Cauchy sequence is a sequence that, for all $\epsilon < 0$ there exists a $p \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $m,n \in p$ $|x_m-x_n|< \epsilon$. However, I'm confused as to how to actually go about proving something is a Cauchy sequence and how in this case the sequence is built up from a different sequence. Any hints or suggestions would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Start with writing an expression for $y_n - y_m$.

Comment: After writing the expression $y_n-y_m$, try to bound its absolute value from above. *Hint* the monotonicity of $(x_n)$ is crucial here.

Comment: Would this be the correct expression for $y_n - y_m$ - $y_n - y_m = (x_1-x_2....(-1)^{n+1}x_n) -(x_1-x_2....(-1)^{m+1}x_m $ ?

Answer (score 2):

Take $\varepsilon>0$. If $n$ is large enough, you have $x_N<\varepsilon$. Pick such a $N$. Now, if $m,n\geqslant N$, you want to prove that $\lvert y_m-y_n\rvert<\varepsilon$. This is trivial if $m=n$. If $m>n$, then$$y_m-y_n=\begin{cases}x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}+\cdots+\pm x_m&\text{ if }n+1\text{ is odd}\\-x_{n+1}+x_{n+1}-\cdots+\pm x_m&\text{ otherwise.}\end{cases}$$But, if $n+1$ is odd,$$y_m-y_n=x_{n+1}-(x_{n+2}-x_{n+3})-\cdots<x_{n+1}<\varepsilon$$and$$y_m-y_n=(x_{n+1}-x_{n+2})+(x_{n+3}-x_{n+4})+\cdots>0.$$Therefore, $\lvert y_m-y_n\rvert<\varepsilon$.  The case in which $n+1$ is even is similar.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I'm still a little confused - How did you get the expression for ym-yn if m>n?

Comment: Suppose, for instance that $m=8$ and that $n=5$. Then\begin{align}y_8-y_5&=(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4+x_5-x_6+x_7-x_8)-(x_1-x_2+x_3-x_4+x_5)\\&=-x_6+x_7-x_8.\end{align}

Comment: Thank you, I'm just still confused on a few parts. So, if $y_m - y_n_ = x_{n+1} -x_{n+2} + x_{n+3} + ... x_m} then how do we get that $y_m-y_n = x_{n+1}-(x_{n+1} - x_{n+3}) - .... What happened to the pluses and why did they turn into minuses? Thank you!

Comment: What you wrote is unreadable and I turned no $+$ into a $-$ or a $-$ into a $+$.

Comment: My apologies, I'm still learning how to use the site. To rephrase, my question is for $n+1$ is odd, how did you get that $_−_=_{+1}−(_{+2}−_{+3})−⋯<_{+1}<$ if, from above that, we have that $_−_=_{+1}−_{+2}+_{+3}−x_m$ if $n+1$ is odd

Comment: You wrote twice the same incomplete sentence.

Comment: I'm asking how did you go from $_−_=_{+1}−_{+2}+_{+3}+_$ to  $_−_=_{+1}−(_{+2}−_{+3})−⋯<_{+1} < \epsilon $

Comment: I used the fact that\begin{align}x_{n+1}-x_{n+2}+x_{n+3}-x_{n+4}+\cdots&=x_{n+1}-\overbrace{(x_{n+2}-x_{n+3})}^{>0}-\overbrace{(x_{n+4}-x_{n+5})}^{>0}-\cdots\\&<x_{n+1}\\&<\varepsilon.\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We need to show that for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a positive integer p such that for all m, n $\geq p$, the absolute difference between y_m and y_n is less than $\epsilon$, i.e., $|y_m - y_n| < \epsilon$.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, since the sequence converges to 0, there exists a positive integer $N_1$ such that for all n $\geq N_1$, we have $|x_n - 0| < \frac{\epsilon}{2}$.

Let m and n be two arbitrary positive constants such that $m, n \geq N_1$. Without loss of generality, assume that $m > n$. We want to show that $|y_m - y_n| < \epsilon$.

First, let's express $y_m - y_n$:

\begin{align*}
y_m - y_n & = (x_1 - x_2 + x_3 - x_4 + \ldots + (-1)^{m+1}x_m) - (x_1 - x_2 + x_3 - x_4 + \ldots + (-1)^{n+1}x_n) \\
& = ((x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{m+1}x_m) - ((x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n+1}x_n) \\
& = ((x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n}x_{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}x_m) - ((x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n+1}x_n).
\end{align*}

Now, we can group terms and simplify:

\begin{align*}
y_m - y_n & = ((x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n}x_{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}x_m) - ((x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n+1}x_n) \\
 = ((x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n}x_{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}x_m) \\
& \quad - (-(x_1 - x_2) - (x_3 - x_4) - \ldots - (-1)^{n+1}x_n) \quad \text{(Distribute the negative sign)} \\
& = ((x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n}x_{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}x_m) \\
& \quad + ((x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n+1}x_n) \quad \text{(Remove the negative sign)}.
\end{align*}

The following equation yields from the above equation by tringle inequality:

\begin{align*}
|y_m - y_n| & \leq |(x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n}x_{n+1} + (-1)^{n+1}x_m| \\
& \quad + |(x_1 - x_2) + (x_3 - x_4) + \ldots + (-1)^{n+1}x_n| \\
& \leq |(x_1 - x_2)| + |(x_3 - x_4)| + \ldots + |(-1)^{n}x_{n+1}| + |(-1)^{n+1}x_m| \\
& \quad + |(x_1 - x_2)| + |(x_3 - x_4)| + \ldots + |(-1)^{n+1}x_n| \\
& = 2\left(|(x_1 - x_2)| + |(x_3 - x_4)| + \ldots + |(-1)^{n}x_{n+1}|\right).
\end{align*}

Then

$2\left(|(x_1 - x_2)| + |(x_3 - x_4)| + \ldots + |(-1)^{n}x_{n+1}|\right)$
$\leq 2\left(\frac{\epsilon}{2} + \frac{\epsilon}{2} + \ldots + \frac{\epsilon}{2}\right)
 = n\epsilon$.

So, we have shown that for any $\epsilon > 0$ and for all m, n $\geq N_1$, $|y_m - y_n| < n\epsilon$.

Now, choose $p = N_1$ so that for all m, n $\geq p$, we have $|y_m - y_n| < n\epsilon$. Since n can be arbitrarily large, as m and n approach infinity, $|y_m - y_n|$ approaches 0. This satisfies the definition of a Cauchy sequence.